# Is it possible to reduce application size by using the highest-quality resources only in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-resources

Google advices on using different sizes of the same resource for different [screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) and [pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

However, all I can read there is the problem of showing smaller resource on bigger screen, or the same screen size with more pixel density.

There I can't see any complaint about problems of showing higher quality content, on lower pixel densities, or smaller screen sizes.

Thus I created a one-activity single-image test application, only using the largest possible resources and tested it on big and small devices, on dense and sparse pixel distributions. And it didn't look bad in my own eyes. Nothing went wrong.

Therefore I thought about reducing app size, only using the highest quality of each resource, and removing lower qualities. Is it a valid approach for improving app size? What pitfalls are there that I've not seen? What problems I might run into in future?

Comment: Or you could just use the new `App Bundles` https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Comment: @tyczj, What an amazing idea. Unfortunately we're not delivering our app via Google Play. But that is exactly what Google should have done years ago. It makes no sense for anyone to pay the cost of downloading and having hidden resources only built for others.

Answer (score 2):

Devices with smaller density typically have also weaker hardware (memory, CPU power). So the extra effort to store and scale down high-res images may be noticeable.

Comment: This.  If someone is really concerned about APK size, you can always download the resources at runtime rather than bundling, and that way grab just what you need.